# How do I run igraph C library functions directly from R base?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, igraph

I tried a copy of `make_tree()`:

```
library(igraph)
myfun <-
function (n, children = 2, mode = c("out", "in", "undirected")) 
{
    mode <- igraph.match.arg(mode)
    mode1 <- switch(mode, out = 0, `in` = 1, undirected = 2)
    on.exit(.Call(R_igraph_finalizer))
    res <- .Call(R_igraph_kary_tree, as.numeric(n), as.numeric(children), 
        as.numeric(mode1))
    if (igraph_opt("add.params")) {
        res$name <- "Tree"
        res$children <- children
        res$mode <- mode
    }
    res
}
myfun(n=3, children=2)
```

This gives:

```
Error in igraph.match.arg(mode) : 
  could not find function "igraph.match.arg"
```

- Q1: how to make `igraph.match.arg()` and `.Call()` available in R base?
- Q2: how to make an overview of all available functions in the igraph C-library.
  A2: unclass(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace("igraph"), all = TRUE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell R from where it should get objects that are not on the search path (e.g., because they are not exported by a package).

```
myfun <-
  function (n, children = 2, mode = c("out", "in", "undirected")) 
  {
    mode <- igraph:::igraph.match.arg(mode)
    mode1 <- switch(mode, out = 0, `in` = 1, undirected = 2)
    on.exit(.Call(igraph:::R_igraph_finalizer))
    res <- .Call(igraph:::R_igraph_tree, as.numeric(n), as.numeric(children), 
                 as.numeric(mode1))
    if (igraph:::igraph_opt("add.params")) {
      res$name <- "Tree"
      res$children <- children
      res$mode <- mode
    }
    res
  }
myfun(n=3, children=2)
#works
```

`R_igraph_kary_tree` is not from the igraph package.

Comment: I got, on Windows 11: `Error in myfun(n = 3, children = 2) : object 'R_igraph_tree' not found`.

Comment: In my configuration `R_igraph_kary_tree` works.

Comment: I tested with igraph version 1.6.0. You might want to update.

Comment: I am testing with dev. version  "1.6.0.9025". Anyway it works.